# error: ‘struct tty_driver’ has no member named ‘ioctl’

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I found similar post but could not find solution so thought will post my question. I am working with a device driver. I know, the function below compiles successfully with 2.6 Kernel Headers and now trying to compile it with "3.2.0-4-686-pae" (Debian). I am getting following error messages,

```
 error: ‘struct tty_driver’ has no member named ‘ioctl’
 error: ‘struct vc_data’ has no member named ‘vc_tty'
```

I checked "tty_driver" in tty_driver.h (which is included in tty.h) and found that

```
int  (*ioctl)(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file * file,
            unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

is defined but not sure why I am getting this error.

Also, I could not find 'vc_tty' included in the 'vc_data' in "console_struct.h" Can anyone please let me know what updates need to be made in order to make it work with "3.2.0-4-686-pae"?

```
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/console_struct.h>

struct tty_driver *my_driver;

static void my_func(unsigned long ptr)
{
    /* Some code */   

    (my_driver->ioctl) (vc_cons[fg_console].d->vc_tty, NULL, KDSETLED,
                *pstatus);

    /* Some more code */
}
```

I have not posted the whole code here but thought will post if needed. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

The "operations" of the `tty_driver` were moved to a separate `struct tty_operations *ops` member at some point, you'll find `ioctl` now.

```
((my_driver->ops)->ioctl)(...);
```

Same thing for the port data in the `struct vc_data`, was moved to a `struct tty_port port` member. So use this instead:

```
vc_cons[fg_console].d->port.tty
```

You can find these sort of changes pretty easily by searching for the exact error messages you're getting (one by one), and looking at the patches and bug reports you will usually find. For simple things like this, it'll work 99% of the time.

Then you can use sites like Linux Cross Reference on [Free Electrons](http://free-electrons.com/) to navigate between different versions of the headers and find the details. (For example, [`include/linux/console_struct.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/console_struct.h).)